# Query returns duplicate records due to multiple values in a column for same record. Need help to filter the query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a customer record with multiple ethnicity code values. Each ethnicity code is given a priority number which is defined in the lookup table. My current select query creates a record for each ethnicity value for a given customer. I'd like to use the priority value and retrieve only the record for the customer that has got a highest priority value. (1 is highest, 99 is lowest priority)

My select query is currently returning a record for each ethnicity code for the customer.

```
select distinct external_id,
pat.patient_id,
eth.ethnicity_code,
et.description,
et.priority
FROM
patient.patient pat
INNER JOIN patient.Ethnicity eth ON pat.patient_id=eth.patient_id
INNER JOIN lookup.LK_EthnicityCode et ON eth.ethnicity_code=et.ethnicity_code
```

My current result set is as below

[image: Actual Result]

My expected result should contain only row 1,2,3,4,7 and 8 in the above result set.

Comment: There are differences in value in three column for the same id. How you like to merge them?

Comment: Can you show the structure of the three tables?

Note that you can rather make a distinct external_id, but if you have other values correlated to this field, your query will actually come up repeating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it using `row_number()`, it will assign 1 (`numberPriority`) to each `patient_id` with the `highest priority` within `patient_id` (1 is highest, 99 is lowest priority).

```
with patients as  (
    select distinct external_id,
    pat.patient_id,
    eth.ethnicity_code,
    et.description,
    et.priority,
    row_number() over (partition by pat.patient_id order by et.priority asc) as numberPriority
    FROM
    patient.patient pat
    INNER JOIN patient.Ethnicity eth ON pat.patient_id=eth.patient_id
    INNER JOIN lookup.LK_EthnicityCode et ON eth.ethnicity_code=et.ethnicity_code
)
select  
    *
from patients
where numberPriority = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also playing with my query and got expected results with the below modification to my original query

```
select distinct external_id,
pat.patient_id,
eth.ethnicity_code,
et.description,
et.priority
FROM
patient.patient pat
INNER JOIN patient.Ethnicity eth ON pat.patient_id=eth.patient_id
INNER JOIN lookup.LK_EthnicityCode et ON eth.ethnicity_code=et.ethnicity_code
And et.priority = ( SELECT min(et1.priority) 
FROM lookup.LK_EthnicityCode et1, patient.Ethnicity eth1
where eth1.ethnicity_code=et1.ethnicity_code
and eth.patient_id=eth1.patient_id )
ORDER BY patient_id
```